# Dell laptop: No bios screen, no sounds or flashing lights. Power light is on

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

As the title suggests, my 4 year old laptop went kaput on me. It is a Dell Inspiron 5110. The hard drive is fine(I put it into my other laptop and it worked perfectly). What could the problem be? I have already tried to force bios crisis recovery, and try to boot Ubuntu from disk. Nothing. If I take the RAM out, there is a beeping sound.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: win10 is not supported , what OS?

Comment: pooched your Bios?  Dell forum user said "I can describe what i did but i am sure i dont think i did something weird and of course i dont recommend this as a solution this issue but it just worked for me :)

1)windows update (check/nothing downloaded)

2) restart

3) re-flashed A11 bios 

4) restart

5)clicked Get Windows app icon (failure/BIOS isnt supported)

6) shut down / removed battery / wait / start

7)clicked Get Windows app icon (Success)

I repeat i dont recommend this as a solution but worked for me"

Comment: doesn't boot at all. should have Ubuntu on it

Comment: change anything to cause this?  RAM? BIOS? vacuum it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out, it is broken, and I need a new processor. I am throwing it away. I found this out when I went to Dell, and they would have charged me more than $300 for a new processor. Not going to happen. However, thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

***[Dell community said this...](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19534608)***

Solution for recovery bios Dell N5110

1. Download the latest firmware from the Dell support
2. Save the exe and create a shortcut with the following parameter: " /writehdrfile"
3. Start the created shortcut and it will create a n5110a11.hdr file rename the file to N5110.hdr
4. Create a shortcut exe file with the following parameter: " /writeromfile"
5. Start the created shortcut and it will create a n5110a11.rom file rename the file to DQ15A11.rom
6. Copy both file "N5110.hdr" and "DQ15A11.rom" to a FAT formatted pendrive's root folder
7. Remove the charger and Battery from the laptop
8. Plug In the pendrive
9. Press & hold END
10. Connect the charger (still hold END)
11. The notebook starts automatically and shows the recovery screen
12. Press enter and wait until finish the flashing
13. Press esc to restart
14. Hopefully problem solved

or start from 7.

Comment: when do I let go of END?

Comment: if recovery screen does not show up.. BIOS is toast

Comment: "Dell community said this" - Please provide cite the source.

Comment: testing out this method...

Comment: OK, thanks so much for the step above. As I booted, the beeps came on. I recognized it as a CPU Cache test failure. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @user45899, sounds like that should be a new question.  If one of these answers solved the problem you presented in this question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That indicates that what you asked here has been solved and helps to identify proven solutions for other readers with a similar problem.  It also awards a little rep to the author and you for the effort.  If you are now at a different stage, with different diagnostic information, post a new, self-contained question reflecting the current state of things, which will have a very different answer.

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding correctly your computer is not turning on at all but the power light is on.

Here are a couple of things you can do, sometimes static power can cause your computer to misbehave clear static power,

1. Remove battery and disconnect from adapter
2. press the power button for about 30 sec to clear static power
3. connect the adapter back and try turning it on

I had the same problem and tried this article which worked for me, you can read more details if you want on [Dell laptop wont turn on](http://accatech.com/dell-inspiron-laptop-wont-turn/)